# The emulator comes up with a lock on the first screen

Tags: android, android-emulator

After I start an Android 3.1 AVD it comes up with a lock screen. How do I get past this screen to view the installed applications.

Comment: just unlock it with the mouse, in the same way you'd unlock a phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the "lock" and slide it across the screen.